# Calculate freq based on three columns in R

Tags: r, frequency

Here is my data frame

```
id    ingredient1    ingredient2    ingredient3
1      apple            milk           cheese
5      pear             apple          
3      lettuces         tomato         salt
12     ribs             tomato         salt
20     cheese           milk           tomato
... ...
```

Here are more than 200 lines
I know how to get the freq by table. But here, I really have no idea how to do it.
This is the ideal output I would like to have:

```
var     freq
apple     2
milk      2
cheese    2
pear      1
lettuces  1
tomato    3
salt      2
ribs      1
... ...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that you want the total frequency from all the 'ingredient' columns, we subset the dataset by removing the first column (`df1[-1]`), then `unlist` it to make a `vector` and get the frequency of unique elements with `table`.  If you need a `data.frame` output, we can wrap it with `as.data.frame`.

```
res <- as.data.frame(table(unlist(df1[-1])))
```

I find some blank elements `''` in the ingredient column.  If you want to remove it,

```
subset(res, Var1!='')
#      Var1 Freq
#2    apple    2
#3   cheese    2
#4 lettuces    1
#5     milk    2
#6     pear    1
#7     ribs    1
#8     salt    2
#9   tomato    3
```

Comment: my instinct was to `melt` this, but this approach is better if the `data.frame` really has only 4 columns

Comment: @MichaelChirico  Yes `melt` is another good option.  But, I thought to keep all with the `base R` functions.  You could convert to `data.table` , `melt` and then using one of the columns, we get the `.N`.

Comment: You could also do: `df %>% gather(key, value, -id) %>% group_by(ingredient = value) %>% tally()`

Comment: @StevenBeaupré  You can post that as an alternative.  Looks nice with `tally`

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  gather(key, value, -id) %>% 
  group_by(ingredient = value) %>% 
  tally()
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [9 x 2]
#
#  ingredient n
#1      apple 2
#2     cheese 2
#3   lettuces 1
#4       milk 2
#5       pear 1
#6       ribs 1
#7       salt 2
#8     tomato 3
#9         NA 1
```

Comment: Two solutions are helpful. But I can not accept both. Sorry about that! Really thank you!